# How do you remove a breakpoint from Safari 4's Javascript debugger?

Tags: javascript, safari, debugging

How do you remove a breakpoint from Safari 4's Javascript debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking it again will disable it (goes a lighter blue), but the line is always highlighted as a breakpoint (or breakpoint woz 'ere).  The visual indication is handy if you find you need to set it again soon after.  A disabled breakpoint behaves exactly like no breakpoint anyway.

Comment: yeah guess this should be fine. it's kinda annoying though :)

Comment: Super duper annoying as you add and remove lines of code -- 'cause, you know, you're debugging and fixing stuff -- and you end up with dozens of light blue "breakpoints" on empty lines and other things that no longer apply.  Ugh.

Answer (score 15):

Or, according to Apple...

"A blue arrow in the gutter means that before that line of code is executed, execution will halt. To temporarily disable the breakpoint, click it; it turns from blue to gray to indicate that it’s disabled. To remove the breakpoint, drag it outside of the gutter."

Comment: Dragging outside the gutter does in fact delete the breakpoint. This is the most correct answer.

Comment: +1 still very annoying that you can't just unset or clear them.

Answer (score 4):

For recent Safari (11 in this case), click on any breakpoint in the left box showing your breakpoints. Hit delete and hold. It will wipe them all out.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while, but in case anyone runs into this now (as I did while doing a late-night debugging session), I was able to go into the Exceptions tab (http://cl.ly/image/1M0K1O0a0T2w) and there was a list of all breakpoints listed below the Uncaught Exceptions (http://cl.ly/image/0Y2I1n3F1c2F). Highlighting the top one and hitting Delete on my keyboard until they were all gone took care of all the breakpoints in short order.